# SQL: Update a table from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have two tables (with sample data):

**tblZone**

```
[ZoneNo]  [Zone]

-----1------Zone1
-----2------Zone2
-----3------Zone3
```

**tblPointsClient**

```
[PolygonID] [Zone Name]

-----0------------Zone1
-----0------------Zone1
-----0------------Zone1
-----0------------Zone2
-----0------------Zone2
-----0------------Zone2
-----0------------Zone3
-----0------------Zone3
-----0------------Zone3
```

Basically, using MySQL, I am trying to update the PolygonID in tblPointsClient by what the ZoneNo is for the Zone in tblZone (if that makes sense).

So when I run this update it should change the PolygonID's to:

```
[PolygonID] [Zone Name]

-----1------------Zone1
-----1------------Zone1
-----1------------Zone1
-----2------------Zone2
-----2------------Zone2
-----2------------Zone2
-----3------------Zone3
-----3------------Zone3
-----3------------Zone3
```

I have tried the following:

```
UPDATE tblPointsClient 
SET tblPointsClient.PolygonID = (
   SELECT ZoneNo FROM tblZones WHERE tblPointsClient.ZoneNo = tblZones.Zone
                                )
```

but this made all the PolygonID's `0`

If anybody could help, that would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE  tblPointsClient a
        INNER JOIN tblZone b
            ON a.`Zone Name` = b.Zone
SET     a.PolygonID = b.ZoneNo
```

for faster performance, add an `INDEX` on column `Zone Name` on table `tblPointsClient` and `Zone` on table `tblZone`.

**UPDATE 1**

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf9bd/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use subquery to achieve this goal:

```
UPDATE tblPointsClient 
SET PolygonID = (SELECT TOP 1 ZoneNo FROM tblZone WHERE Zone = [Zone Name])
WHERE PolygonID = 0
```

I have created code for updating only rows with `PolygonID = 0`